# Site.com - Incorrectly Escaping Image URLs

Tags: site.com

Recently, it appears there was an update to the way Site.com renders images in a Data Repeater. Here is the scenario:

We had a Site.com site that was working perfectly. We looped over a set of objects using the Data Repeater. Each of these objects had a URL field associated to it that correlated to a relevant image. Each of these URLs contained an ampersand as part of the URL parameters. For instance, we have an image at http://foo.com?param=one&other=two - Using this URL field, we created a Data Element under the Data Repeater. This Data Element was rendered as an image correctly in the preview, preview site, and then even the published site. The code was rendering properly as:

```
<img src="http://foo.com?param=one&other=two" alt="Foo"/>
```

Sometime this morning (1/15/13), this all changed. The code that was generated became:

```
<img src="http://foo.com?param=one&amp;other=two" alt="Foo"/>
```

Notice the change in the src of the img tag. It escaped the

```
&
```

and replaced it with the HTML entity

```
&amp;
```

This caused serious issues because the image broke across all of the records. During testing, we noticed that this issue only occurred when rendering a Data Element as an Image. If we rendered it as Text, the URL displayed correctly. The really perplexing part of this is that the image was only broken when fully published. The Data Element preview and the site preview worked correctly.

With this being on a production site, we had to go ahead with a workaround by using a custom code block and generating our own img tag, but this is a serious concern now moving forward.

I attempted to do some research and find out if there was an update to Site.com or what really triggered this change. I couldn't find any documentation for any changes today.

**My main question is what happened?** What caused this issue? Why is there no documentation about this change? There is now a large concern other aspects can change with no warning causing sweeping detrimental changes to production sites. I am hoping someone here may have some insight or may be able to point me in the right direction.

**EDIT (1/18/13):** I have been working back and forth with Salesforce support on this issue. I discussed with a Salesforce engineer on the exact issue and helped him replicate the problem. From the latest response on the case, it sounds like he has replicated the issue and is working on getting the issue resolved. I will be sure to update this issue once I find out what happened and once I found out what fixes the problem.

**EDIT (1/21/13):** The case has been escalated and I am waiting to hear from a different Salesforce engineer. Will update when more information becomes available.

**EDIT (1/24/13):** On 1/22/13 I was contacted by the next tier of support. They have indicated they believe it is their issue and they are currently looking into it. I am still waiting for an update. Will update when I get more information.

**EDIT (1/30/13):** I am still waiting to hear back from support about what happened with this issue, when we can expect a fix, and how these types of issues can be avoided in the future.

**EDIT (2/1/13):** This has been handed over to R&D. I am working with Tier 3 support and they are providing me updates regularly. This does appear to be a legitimate issue. I will update with more information when it becomes available.

Comment: Interesting! I think opening a support case is going to be your quickest and most direct resolution. It definitely seems like some new entity escaping has been implemented on the SFDC side of things and there's not much you can do there.

Comment: can you post the case# of the case you open?

Comment: I submitted a case (08617411)

Comment: From the spring '13 release notes they actually tightened up html markup escaping in component descriptions and page layout section names as well so this was probably a side-effect of something they were doing across the board.

Comment: @grigriforce - Site.com isn't available in sandboxes, so it shouldn't be something in spring '13, but it looks like it is across the board.  I can't add picklist values that have the ampersand, for example Food & Beverage on a picklist for Account Industry filtering.  It strips them out.  (I tried using entity and url encoded values as well). Workaround is to use custom code blocks which is not ideal for a CMS.

Comment: @PeterKnolle This seems like a pretty big change. You would think they would mention it in the release notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tier 3 support has confirmed this was a regression bug. According to the engineer I was working with, they will try to get this fix deployed sometime this week. However, I must point out that all releases are tentative so it may not be that quickly. You can follow the status of the bug here - http://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000Su4WAAS - If you are effected by the issue as well you can also use that link to check out when it will be fixed on you particular instance.

Thanks to all of the comments on my original question. You helped get this resolved.